# Is there any way that classes always inherit from some base class

Tags: python, django

In my application i have the requirement of keppling logs of all models changes and delete.
So i have created baseclass `Audit` and extended all classes from it.

I have overridden save , delete methods in it so that i keep old chnages as well when we do some updation.

I want to know that is there any better way of doing that rather than extending all classes fron base class. Or is it all right like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this use case, you may be able to write a generic function that could be used with django signals.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Comment: Can i override delete function with djnago signals because wheneever someone deletes something i am updating database field DELETED TO 1 rather than actually deleting. can signals do that

Comment: No, you couldn't prevent delete from happening. If your doing that, you'd need to override the actual delete command. If this is the behavior your after, you may also want to implement a custom manager

Comment: using signals does seem like a better approach because it is more decoupled and it also works on queryset operations (like deleting objects in bulk), whereas overwritten `save` and `delete` will not.

Comment: @Jeff But if i use custom manager , doesn't i have to define that for every class?

Comment: in order to override the queryset methods you need a manager though. You may want to only query with `deleted = 0` and change the behavior of the delete method on querysets.I think with proxy inheritance you can set the manager in the parent